# Recording a lecture, mirroring Ipad to Windows PC

Tags: video, video-recording, windows, ipad

I would like to record a lecture for my maths students. I want to write it on my Ipad (in goodnotes), mirror Ipad on my PC laptop, and use OBS on my PC to combine the image of the Ipad with the input of my video camera (+ my voice).

I wonder, what are the best ways to mirror Ipad to my PC?

I am aware of three methods. 1) Make a zoom call to myself. 2) Use LonelyScreen 3) Use Apowersoft. Are there better ways (preferably free)?